# Adding two hex numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to add two hex numbers "920001A" "920001F"

```
BigInteger number1 = BigInteger.Parse("920001A", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger number2 = BigInteger.Parse("920001F", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.Add(number1, number2);
MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString("X"));
```

However output should be "12400039" but its coming "F2400039"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both `number1` and `number2` are negative, [as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?view=netframework-4.7#System_Numerics_BigInteger_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_):

> If value is a hexadecimal string, the `Parse(String, NumberStyles)` method interprets value as a negative number stored by using two's complement representation if its first two hexadecimal digits are greater than or equal to 0x80. In other words, the method interprets the highest-order bit of the first byte in value as the sign bit. To make sure that a hexadecimal string is correctly interpreted as a positive number, the first digit in value must have a value of zero.

The result is negative (which you'll see if you print the decimal value). It's formatted as F2400039 for the same reason that the input is parsed as a negative number, although I haven't found documentation supporting that yet.

As per the documentation, just add a leading zero when parsing:

```
BigInteger number1 = BigInteger.Parse("0920001A", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger number2 = BigInteger.Parse("0920001F", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

You'll then get the correct result.

Comment: @Chetan.B: I've shown that already - parse with a leading `0` so that it parses them as positive values, and then you can add them with no problems.

Comment: @Chetan.B: I'm not sure what your second comment is meant to indicate. If you don't need `BigInteger`, don't use it. I assumed that because you *are* using `BigInteger`, you're expecting values outside the range of `long`.